# What is the behavior of the C++ method ostream::exceptions(iostate state) supposed to be?

Tags: c++, exception, iostream, ostream

I'm in the process of writing my own output streaming library and I'm trying to mimic std::ostream behaviors where it doesn't conflict with the new behaviors I'm trying to achieve.  Currently I'm trying to mimic this interface inherited from ios:

```
std::ostream::exceptions(ios::iostate state)
```

According to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/):

*"this method sets a new exception mask for the stream and clears the stream's error state flags (as if member clear() was called)."*

It wasn't clear to me whether this meant all flags would be cleared or only the ones being set in the exceptions mask, so I wrote a test program but got quite unexpected results.  Here's the program:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ostringstream oss;
    try
    {
        cout << "            badbit           = " << ios::badbit        << "\n";
        cout << "            eofbit           = " << ios::eofbit        << "\n";
        cout << "            failbit          = " << ios::failbit       << "\n\n";

        cout << "            oss.rdstate()    = " << oss.rdstate()      << "\n";
        cout << "            oss.exceptions() = " << oss.exceptions()   << "\n\n";

        cout << "executing:  oss.setstate(ios::badbit | ios::failbit);" << "\n";
        oss.setstate(ios::badbit | ios::failbit);
        cout << "            oss.rdstate()    = " << oss.rdstate()      << "\n";
        cout << "            oss.exceptions() = " << oss.exceptions()   << "\n\n";

        cout << "executing:  oss.exceptions(ios::failbit);"             << "\n";
        oss.exceptions(ios::failbit);
        cout << "            oss.rdstate()    = " << oss.rdstate()      << "\n";
        cout << "            oss.exceptions() = " << oss.exceptions()   << "\n";
    }
    catch(const exception& x)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "**** EXCEPTION THROWN ****"                            << "\n";
        cout << argv[0] << ":  " << x.what() << endl;
        cout << "            oss.rdstate()    = " << oss.rdstate()      << "\n";
        cout << "            oss.exceptions() = " << oss.exceptions()   << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cerr << argv[0] << ":  unknown exception." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
matt@dworkin:~/dev/ostream/libs/ostream$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

matt@dworkin:~/dev/ostream/libs/ostream$ g++ --std=c++17 foo.cpp
matt@dworkin:~/dev/ostream/libs/ostream$ ./a.out

            badbit           = 1
            eofbit           = 2
            failbit          = 4

            oss.rdstate()    = 0
            oss.exceptions() = 0

executing:  oss.setstate(ios::badbit | ios::failbit);
            oss.rdstate()    = 5
            oss.exceptions() = 0

executing:  oss.exceptions(ios::failbit);

**** EXCEPTION THROWN ****
./a.out:  basic_ios::clear: iostream error
            oss.rdstate()    = 5
            oss.exceptions() = 4
```

So based on the cplusplus.com docs, I wasn't expecting an exception to be thrown at all.  And as can be seen from the output generated from within the exception handler, no state flags were ever cleared.  So is this a compiler bug, a documentation bug, or am I missing something?

As an aside, I prefer the behavior exhibited over the behavior documented.  Seems sorta strange to me that a request to throw on errors would have the side-affect of erasing existing errors.  I actually first implemented it the same way g++ apparently does (assuming this was the way it would surely work), and only then read the docs for this method.

Comment: "According to cplusplus.com:" - you are trying to write a stream library and you are using one of the crappiest resources on the internet to do it? At least use cppreference.com. And really better, forget about it.

Comment: Pleas confirm: Your question is  "Why did I get an exception on `failbit` if stream exceptions are turned on after `failbit` is set?"

Comment: @Neil Butterworth.  Perhaps "my own streaming library" is inaccurate as it is really just an abstract wrapper that attempts to add new functionality to some existing output library (e.g., ostream).  But I am keeping my own exceptions mask, and error state flags (as I don't want to be tied to ostream as a backing).  But all this is beyond the scope of my original question.

Comment: @user4581301:  Yes, that is one of my questions (because it seems to conflict with the claims made at cplusplus.com).  Also, a second question is that cplusplus.com says that a side-affect of calling exceptions is calling clear() (which should clear error state flags), but no flags are cleared.

Comment: [The C++ Standard says `clear` is called](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/iostate.flags). I'd believe it. Note that *basic_ios::clear: iostream error* suggests that it's `clear` that threw the exception. This is what interested me enough to look it up. Check the link and look at what the Standard says `clear` does. Still unpacking how to explain what that means in my head. If you manage it before I do, self answer.

Comment: @user4581301:  Ahh...so the standard says clear(rdstate()) is called -- not clear().  The function clear is named sorta funny as it actually SETS the flags to whatever you pass.  So calling clear(rdstate())  cannot possibly change the flags.  It's only purpose (surely) is to make sure an exception is thrown when an exception flag is set that overlaps with an existing error state flag.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm surprised by how much is wired to run through `clear`; even `setstate` uses `clear` to do the setting. So `clear` is called, cplusplus.com: is right about that, but it's not called to clear the exception resulting in some misleading reading. You may have noticed from @NeilButterworth 's comment that cplusplus.com is not well respected. It's not and this case is a good example of why, when it came down to the nitty-gritty behavioral details whoever wrote that page missed the mark.

Comment: Yes, I did appreciate that particular information from Neil....  It's unfortunate because I think cplusplus.com has superior navigation and searching.  It is not surprising to me that setstate uses clear.  Clear is the setter.  setstate is a facade over clear to make it easier to set particular bits without changing others. You don't want two methods setting the bits.

Comment: Unfortunately it does allow counter-intuitive oddness like `oss.clear(ios::failbit);` setting the `failbit` rather than clearing it. I'm not sure I like that. This behaviour is at least, well documented.

Comment: I agree.  If it were me, I would have added another method.  1) Rename setstate to setflags (since that's what it's really for).  2) Then rename clear(state) to setstate(state) and not have a default value for the arg.   3) Then offer the no-arg method clear() that is just a convenience method that calls setstate(0).  Would be much more intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cplusplus.com is wrong. They are correct that `clear` is called by `exceptions`, but it is **not** called to clear the state and the state is **not** cleared.

In spite of the name, `clear` is used in the back end by iostreams, [including `setstate` itself](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/iostate.flags), to do the grunt work for a great deal of setting, not just clearing, of the stream's state. As such, it is the logical place to house the raising of exceptions and other flag-related behaviours.

In `exceptions` it appears `clear` is being used primarily test for existing flags to raise an exception should any of the desired flags already be set. To actually clear the flags after the exception, a call to `clear` is still required to remove the error flags.